# unwrap picture of a half cylinder in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, transformation

My problem is as follows:

[image]

I have the picture of a half cylinder taken from a horizontal perspective and it has square grid lines on it, so I was wondering how can I implement in MATLAB to unwrap this half cylinder so all my grid cells become the same size? I know I will loose lots of resolution in the edge cells and a simple linear interpolation should do the trick, but I do not know how to tell MATLAB to do this. Also I know the geometrical properties of the cylinder, radius and height. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the approach I am using, but I am trying to find the transformation that will make the edges be same size as inner cells.

```
im=imread('Capture.png');
imshow(im);
impixelinfo

r = @(x) sqrt(x(:,1).^2 + x(:,2).^2);
w = @(x) atan2(x(:,2), x(:,1));
f = @(x) [sqrt(r(x)) .* cos(w(x)), sqrt(r(x)) .* sin(w(x))];
g = @(x, unused) f(x);

tform2 = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], g, []);
im3 = imtransform(im, tform2, 'UData', [-1 1], 'VData', [-1 1], ...
'XData', [-1 1], 'YData', [-1 1]);

figure,
imshow(im3)
```

Comment: my approach is based in this process http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/08/04/spatial-transformations-defining-and-applying-custom-transforms/

Comment: the function define the matrix transformation that tform2 is going to implement. Its the approach i am taking but the functions should be such that the transformation is done only in the X axis and thats what i am having trouble with

Comment: ah, I missed the `g` in `tform2`, apologies. The assignment for `g` is rather obsolete though, since you actually call a variable `unused` and have `g` be an exact copy of `f` in this case

Comment: @felipegarcia can we see the image?

Comment: i don't have the reputation point to upload an image, is there a workaround?

Comment: Post a link and someone with enough reputation will add it

Comment: @felipegarcia I think you should have enough reputation now, with the 2 upvotes you've gotten on your question.

Comment: ok it should be there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the transformation is much simpler than what you're trying to do. Take a look at the (forward) transformation to take a flat grid and wrap it around a cylinder. The coordinates along the axis of the cylinder (the `y` coordinates, in this case) are unchanged. If we take the range of the grid coordinates in the `x` direction to be [-1,1], the coordinates on the cylinder will be:

> sin(x × π/2)

Since this is the *forward* transformation going from a grid to the cylinder, it is also the *inverse* transformation going from the cylinder to the grid.

```
f = @(x, unused) [sin(x (:, 1) * pi / 2), x(:, 2)]
tform2 = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], f, []);
im3=imtransform(img, tform2, 'UData', [-1 1], 'VData', [-1 1], ...
                             'XData', [-1 1], 'YData', [-1 1]);
```

Result:

[image: transformed image]

This still isn't perfect, primarily because the original image has borders around it that we're transforming along with the rest of the image. This could be improved by cropping the image to contain only the cylinder portion.

Comment: awesome this seems to do the trick the cropping part is already implemented somewhere else in the code with some other projection corrections, i was having problem with the custom transformation and understanding the syntax, thank you very much

Comment: Beaker thanks for all your help, one more question, what if the cylinder is at an angle? is there a transformation for the y axis that can take into account the angle at which the picture was taken?

Comment: That's a bit more complex. Assuming the rotation is about the center of the image, you would have to multiply the results above by the appropriate [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). If the center of rotation is somewhere else, you would have to translate the center to the origin and back as well. If you need more assistance, it would be better to start a new question so you can post a sample image.

Comment: ok i will do that right now, the rotation matrix seems like the perfect approach.